# Exclude specific dir from $PATH

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I've multiple MPI variations on my system. Each one is used for compile of specific application. I am looking for an script to exclude specific dir from $PATH to wrap application execution with the corresponding MPI. Is there any simple way to do so?

Comment: export PATH="/path/that/i/want"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps something along the lines of:

```
with-excluded-path () {      
    echo "$PATH" | sed "s,$1:,,g"
}

or 

with-excluded-path () {
    echo "$PATH" | awk -vORS=":" -vRS=":" '$1 == "'$1'" { next }; {print $1}'
}

PATH=$(with-excluded-path "/path/to/exclude") /bin/application
```

Or simply add the desired MPI path to the head of PATH:

```
export PATH="/opt/the/mpi/i/want:$PATH"
```

Comment: +1 for adding the known path to the head of the `PATH`. Trying to remove the path is more complex than necessary.